# OpenLayers place a polygon on the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm coding a web application for a lawnmower robot anti-theft device.

The first thing I did was draw a map, which works, and here's the result:

Image -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVvG3.png

The next thing I had to do was to add a polygon on the map, which represents the area in which the robot may be, outside of which an alarm sounds.
The problem is that the Polygon doesn't appear on my screen, and its area according to OpenLayers is 0 :/

Here is my code :

```js
function draw_poly(points, style) {
  const poly = new ol.geom.Polygon([new ol.geom.LinearRing(points.map(p=>[p.long, p.lat]))], style)
  console.log(poly.getArea())
  console.log(points.map(p=>[p.long, p.lat]))
  return new ol.Feature({
        geometry: poly
      });
}
[...]

const mower_limit_rect = draw_poly([
  {lat: 44.059052, long: 1.344245},
  {lat: 44.059022, long: 1.344543},
  {lat: 44.058733, long: 1.344482},
  {lat: 44.058773, long: 1.344246}
], {
strokeColor: "#00FF00",
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWidth: 3,
fillColor: "#00FF00",
fillOpacity: 0.8
});

[...]

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [mower, mower_limit_rect]
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});


const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    }),
    vectorLayer
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([14,44]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

Thanks you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The polygon should be constructed directly from coordinates, and it must be closed (i.e. the final coordinate is the sames as the first).  It must also be transformed from lon/lat to the view projection.  The geometery constructor does not take a style parameter.  You will need to construct an OpenLayers style from the values in your style object and set that as the feature style.  The separate color and opacity values will need to be combined as rgba color arrays.

```
function draw_poly(points, style) {

  const closedPoints = points.concat([points[0]]);
  const poly = new ol.geom.Polygon([closedPoints.map(p=>[p.long, p.lat])]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
  const feature = new ol.feature(poly);

  const fillColor = ol.color.asArray(style.fillColor).slice();
  fillColor[3] = style.fillOpacity;
  const strokeColor = ol.color.asArray(style.strokeColor).slice();
  strokeColor[3] = style.strokeOpacity;
  const olStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: fillColor
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: strokeColor,
      width: style.strokeWidth
    })
  });
  feature.setStyle(olStyle);
  return feature;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You really help me, it's true that it seems quite stupid like that, but I have a lot of trouble with the OpenLayers documentation.